# area under the precision-recall curve in R or other summary quantities

Tags: r, auc

I plan to use the precision-recall plot (PR plot) to compare models. See the attached figure (partial screenshot, sorry!) below. Obviously I have the true positives, true negatives, false positives and false negatives at hand, and I need a **a single summary quantity** for each model. Here are my questions:

1. Area Under the PR curve (AUC) is the first quantity, but I don't know how to calculate that in R. I do NOT want to use any package like `ROCR` because all the codes are written by myself and I hope to write my own codes using the quantities available. It seems that there are many ways -- I hope to know which one is the most implementable.
2. Another quantity is the F-measure: a measure that combines precision and recall is the harmonic mean of precision and recall, the traditional F-measure or balanced F-score. However,  I am curious if this is better than the AUC in #1 or they are describing different things? Moreover, since I have a bunch of Recall and Precision values, how can I calculate **a single F measure** in this case (see Figure below).

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: I'd start by looking at the code already written for these functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To calculate the AUC of a curve, you can use a numeric integration function such as `trapz()` in the **caTools** package.

`auc <- trapz(recall, precision)`

The F-score is the harmonic mean for a given cutoff value.  In your case, you would get many F-scores for each curve so it would not summarize the curve as you like.

The AUC describes the performance of the model across possible values of the continuous output from the model.  The F-score describes a model at a particular cutpoint.  It is more of a way to combine recall and precision to a single statistic.

Be careful when explaining it though.  Usually, AUC is discussed in the context of sensitivity and specificity.

Comment: thanks, but according to the document, "Trapezoid rule is not the most accurate way of calculating integrals (it is exact for linear functions), for example Simpson's rule (exact for linear and quadratic functions) is more accurate."

Comment: That is true when the curve you are estimating the area under is non-linear between the points used in the estimation (_i.e._ the observed values of recall and precision).  When you are estimating the AUC using non-parametric methods (which is what you are doing unless you model the curve), the curve is linear between the points.  This causes the Trapezoid rule to be exact.  In practice, however, there is little difference between the methods when the curve is reasonably well-behaved.